# TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not iterable (VS Code: Python geopandas)

Tags: python, apple-m1, geopandas, multipolygons

In my anaconda env, I have installed geopandas just fine but I am unable to make plots in Visual Studio Code due to the error:

> TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not iterable.

I am quite new to programming, and so far, I encountered many difficulties running Visual Code Studio on Mac M1 - is it a common error? Should I switch to a different IDE?

**Code:
**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
world_data = gpd.read_file(r'/Users/xxxxx/world.shp')
world_data
world_data.plot()
```

**Error:
**

> /Users/lantyynka/opt/anaconda3/envs/datax/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py:48: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: The 'type' attribute is deprecated, and will be removed in the future. You can use the 'geom_type' attribute instead.
> if geom.type.startswith(prefix):
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/Users/lantyynka/opt/anaconda3/envs/datax/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 921, in plot
> return plot_dataframe(self, *args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/lantyynka/opt/anaconda3/envs/datax/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py", line 615, in plot_dataframe
> return plot_series(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/lantyynka/opt/anaconda3/envs/datax/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py", line 413, in plot_series
> _plot_polygon_collection(
> File "/Users/lantyynka/opt/anaconda3/envs/datax/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py", line 129, in _plot_polygon_collection
> geoms, multiindex = _flatten_multi_geoms(geoms)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/lantyynka/opt/anaconda3/envs/datax/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py", line 49, in _flatten_multi_geoms
> for poly in geom:
> TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not iterable

Thank you in advance for any help!:)

I tried running the code in the terminal as well as the interactive window through Jupyter. Both attempts resulted in the same error.

I also tried installing older version of shapely but it did not work.

Comment: MultiPolygons were iteratable in Shapely 1.x,  so there seems to be some kind of version conflict in your conda environment. How did you verify that Geopandas & co installation was a success? What are your Geopandas and Shapely versions ( `gpd.show_versions()` )? You can also try with a more-or-less known Shp to see if it somehow makes a difference, i.e. use `world_data = gpd.read_file('https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip')` to load your dataset from Natural Earth.

Comment: Starting with a clean environment would not hurt either - https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#creating-a-new-environment